# Reactor - Publish behavior

Tags: project-reactor

I am very confused with publish behavior in Flux. Why the second subscriber does not print anything but the first one does. It is a hot publisher and values are emitted once a second. both should share same elements.

```
    Flux<String> flux = Flux.fromIterable(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"))
                                    .publish()
                                    .autoConnect()
                                    .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));

    flux.subscribe(s -> System.out.println("1 - " + s));
    flux.subscribe(s -> System.out.println("2 - " + s));
```

Interestingly share method shows the output for both subscribers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact it's a "hot publisher" means that you may miss values if they're emitted before you subscribe, which is what's happening here - the first subscriber is causing the `Flux` to start publishing, and it publishes all its values before your second subscriber.

You may expect `delayElements()` to change this behaviour, as it's delaying each one by a second, which should be more than enough time for the second subscriber to subscribe. However, this doesn't happening as you're only delaying the elements *after* the `publish()` and `autoconnect()` calls - or to put it another way, only *after* the `Flux` has been made "hot". This means all the values are emitted near instantly, before being delayed, and before the second subscriber gets a chance to subscribe.

Instead, I suspect you want the `delayElements()` call *before* it's a hot Flux as follows:

```
Flux<String> flux = Flux.fromIterable(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"))
        .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .publish()
        .autoConnect();
```

This will then delay the elements before the `Flux` becomes hot, almost certainly giving your second subscriber enough time to subscribe, and printing both sets of results as you expect.